# What word means a rare but destructive natural event?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a word that describes a natural phenomenon which rarely occurs, yet when it does so, it causes widespread destruction?

Comment: What does high intensity mean here? What sorts of events are you thinking of?  You mean like supernovae or climate-changing meteor impacts or lunar eclipses?

Comment: The word is *catastrophe, natural catastrophe*, or *natural disaster*.

Comment: ekpyrosis: the destruction of the universe by fire -ekpyrotic

Comment: @tchrist exactly the sort of events you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Some words that come to mind are *volcanic*, *eruptive*, *cataclysmic*, *orgasmic* and *paroxysmal*.